# XSD element to to fetch Element Based on Starting and Ending Position

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

```
28169        199855888107336BAP05185    2850204722 
38169        19985588810733600001BAP05185    2850204722
```

This is my file data and I want to create xsd schema that fetch value from 20 to 28 character number.

Comment: Using what system?   Flat files schemas don't have a standard, and different systems have different implementations.  e.g. I could tell you what the schema would be in BizTalk, but that would not work elsewhere.

Comment: Also that looks like it might be a mix of delimited and positional or it is tab delimited, as the end elements are offset from each other. So you might want to give more details of the definition of the file. e.g. all the fields, rather than just the one, and the end of line delimiters and any other delimiters used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BizTalk the following Flat Files schema would parse it, Field2 containing what you are after.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch2.SO72451573" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch2.SO72451573" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" root_reference="Root" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" />
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Record">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="positional" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Field1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" pos_length="19" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Field2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="2" justification="left" pos_length="9" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Field" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="3" justification="left" pos_length="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Would parse it into the following XML

```
<Root xmlns="http://Scratch2.SO72451573">
    <Record xmlns="">
        <Field1>28169        199855</Field1>
        <Field2>888107336</Field2>
        <Field>B</Field>
        <Field>A</Field>
        <Field>P</Field>
        <Field>0</Field>
        <Field>5</Field>
        <Field>1</Field>
        <Field>8</Field>
        <Field>5</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field/>
        <Field/>
        <Field/>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field>8</Field>
        <Field>5</Field>
        <Field>0</Field>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field>0</Field>
        <Field>4</Field>
        <Field>7</Field>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field/>
    </Record>
    <Record xmlns="">
        <Field1>38169        199855</Field1>
        <Field2>888107336</Field2>
        <Field>0</Field>
        <Field>0</Field>
        <Field>0</Field>
        <Field>0</Field>
        <Field>1</Field>
        <Field>B</Field>
        <Field>A</Field>
        <Field>P</Field>
        <Field>0</Field>
        <Field>5</Field>
        <Field>1</Field>
        <Field>8</Field>
        <Field>5</Field>
        <Field/>
        <Field/>
        <Field/>
        <Field/>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field>8</Field>
        <Field>5</Field>
        <Field>0</Field>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field>0</Field>
        <Field>4</Field>
        <Field>7</Field>
        <Field>2</Field>
        <Field>2</Field>
    </Record>
</Root>
```